# Python importing functions directly from package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a package with the following structure:

```
package
|__ __init__.py
|__ file.py
```

The contents of `file.py` are

```py
def foo():
    print("bar")
```

So far, in my `__init__.py` I've put

```py
from . import file
```

However, when I import `package`, I can only use `foo()` as `package.file.foo()`.
Is there any way I could modify `__init__.py` so that I can use `foo()` as `package.foo()`?

Comment: How about ```from package.file import foo```?

Comment: `from .file import foo`